# Various definitions of Connections on bundles

Tags: dg.differential-geometry

Let $X$ be a smooth manifold and suppose I have a smooth vector bundle $E\to X$  which admits a connection $D$. Then on an open set $U\subset X$ where $E$ is trivial, once I choose a frame, say $e_1,...e_n$, I get a connection matrix by the rule $D(e_i)=\sum_{j=1}^{n}e_j\otimes\omega_{ji}^U$ (a column vector of 1 forms). If $V \subset X$ is another open set where $E$ is trivial and I choose a frame over $V$, say $f_1,...f_n$, then similarly I get $\omega^V$. Let $e_i=\sum_{j=1}^{n}g_{ji}f_j$. Then we have $\omega^V=g\omega^U g^{-1}-dgg^{-1}$.

On the other hand, we can form the associated principal $GL_n$ bundle $P\stackrel{\pi}{\to} X$, with $GL_n$ acting on the right. A connection on $P$ is a $GL_n$ invariant splitting of $\pi^*\Omega_X\to \Omega_P$. Locally, after we choose trivialisations for $P$ using the frames for $E$ chosen earlier, this becomes equivalent to giving a $GL_n$ equivariant splitting of $\Omega_U\to \Omega_U\oplus\Omega_G$, which is equivalent to giving a map $\Omega_{G,e}\to\Omega_{U,x}$ for each point $x\in U$, this gives the $\omega^U$. If $x\in U\cap V$, then the point $(x,A)$ in $U\times G$ is identified with the point $(x,gA)$ in $V\times G$. The gluing gives the following relation 
$\omega^V=g\omega^U g^{-1}+dgg^{-1}$. This is different from the one above. Is that OK?

Comment: I'm pretty sure the second one you have is correct, but the first one is not.  I've worked it out before and the wikipedia article http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connection_form agrees.

Comment: @Eric: The wiki article agrees with the first one. 

Comment: The first formula is correct, so clearly there is something wrong with the second.  Since you give no details, it's difficult to say where it is that the error has crept up.

Comment: I don't see how the first formula is correct.  Say $E$ is 1-d with frames $f$ and $e$ with $f = ge$ and $De = \omega\otimes e$.  Then $Df = dg \otimes e + g \nabla e = dg\otimes e + g \omega \otimes e = (dg + g\omega) \otimes g^{-1} f = ((dg)g^{-1} + \omega)\otimes f$.  So the connection form in the $f$ frame is $(dg) g^{-1} + \omega$.  This agrees with the second formula but not the first.

Comment: Just noticed your transition functions are going the opposite way I had them.  So yea, the first formula is correct (replace my $g$ with $g^{-1}$).  Maybe you made the same mistake I did in getting at the second equation?

Comment: @Eric: I was just going to tell you that. Thanks.

Comment: @Jose: Locally, $\Omega_P=\Omega_U\oplus\Omega_{GL_n}$. So the section restricted to $U$ is just a $GL_n$ equivariant section $\Omega_{GL_n}\to \Omega_U$, which gives us $\omega^U$. We just need to check what the gluing condition tells us. If $x\in U\cap V$, then the point $(x,A)$ in $U\times GL_n$ is identified with $(x,gA)$ in $V\times GL_n$. This map from $U\cap V\times GL_n\to U\cap V\to GL_n$ induces a pullback at the level of forms. I just put these together. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

I don't think there's any problem here. The question you want to ask is: Given a section $u$ of $E$, whether you get a consistent answer for $\nabla u$, using either frame. In other words, does $\nabla (u^ie_i) = \nabla (\hat{u}^i\hat{e}_i)$ using your change of frame formulas? I think you'll see what's going on if you work this out.

Let me elaborate a little bit. I never write change of frame formulas for the connection $1$-forms in isolation, because I am always confused by whether I should be acting on the frame by $g$ or $g^{-1}$. And whether $G$ is supposed to be acting on the right or left. But I know I will always get the right answer if I think about applying the connection to local section $u$ and expand it using two different local frames. Everything always automatically works out correctly when I do it this way.

Comment: My problem is on the one hand I get $\omega^V=g\omega^Ug^{-1}-dgg^{-1}$ and on the other hand I get $\omega^V=g\omega^Ug^{-1}+dgg^{-1}$. I have checked the calculation several times and so I think I am goofing up with some definition?? 

Comment: Let me try to extend Deane Yang's answer (hope it is OK): Suppose you are looking at the same connection and the same trivialization in these two different ways. Do you get the same form $\omega^U$?

Comment: Your calculation is correct. Please focus on an actual section of $E$ and expand it using two different frames. You'll see why everything is actually OK.

Comment: t3suji (and anyone else), you're more than welcome to expand on my answer or even rewrite it differently as a separate answer. I'm being a little coy, because I prefer students to struggle and figure these things out on their own. But if someone else wants to explain what's going on, they're welcome to do so.

Comment: @Deane Yang : The first calculation is correct. It's the second one I am worried about, the one which involves the principal bundle. Are you saying that the second one is fine too? 

Comment:  @t3suji: I am not sure I understand your question, but I think the answer is no. I am getting $\-\omega^U$.

Comment: Both formulas appear correct to me.

Comment: If both formulas are correct, then we would have the following: Start with a vector bundle $E\to X$. Then using trivialisations, we get connection forms $\omega^U$ which satisfy $\omega^V=g\omega^Ug^{-1}-dgg^{-1}$. Then $-\omega^U$ satisfy $\omega^V=g\omega^Ug^{-1}+dgg^{-1}$ which is exactly what is needed to define a connection on the principal $GL_n$ bundle. Conversely, we can go backwards also. 

This seems to suggest that for a principle bundle we should define curvature as $d\omega-\omega\wedge\omega$, as opposed to $d\omega+\omega\wedge\omega$ in the case of a vector bundle.

Comment: I encourage you to read the second paragraph of my answer (which I just added).

Comment: In other words, the omega's in the second calculation are minus the omega's in the first. Hence the sign difference in the transition formulae.